# Extracting minimum of vector

Tags: vector, min, erase

I'm extracting the min from a vector.

Say vector = [0, inf, inf, inf];

```
ExtractSmallest(vector) = 0;
```

and then vector = [0, 1, inf, inf];

but now, we've already seen 0. Thus,

```
ExtractSmallest(vector) = 1;
```

I represent this in my code by doing `nodes.erase(nodes.begin() + smallestPosition);`

But, I now realize that erasing is very bad. Is there a way to achieve this **without** erasing the vectors? Just skipping over the ones we've already seen?

```
Node* CGraph::ExtractSmallest(vector<Node*>& nodes)
{


    int size = nodes.size();
    if (size == 0) return NULL;
    int smallestPosition = 0;
    Node* smallest = nodes.at(0);


    for (int i=1; i<size; ++i)
    {

        Node* current = nodes.at(i);

        if (current->distanceFromStart <
            smallest->distanceFromStart)
        {
            smallest = current;
            smallestPosition = i;

        }
    }

    nodes.erase(nodes.begin() + smallestPosition);      


    return smallest;


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1** You can have an additional `vector<bool>` on which you iterate in parallel. When you find the smallest element, mark that position in the `bool` vector as `true`. Whenever you iterate, skip the positions in both vectors that are marked as `true`.

**Option 2** If order is not important, keep the number of elements removed so far. When you find the minimum, swap positions with the first non-excluded element. On a new iteration, start from the first non-excluded element.

**Option 3** If order is not important, sort the array. (this takes `O(n*log(n))`). Removal will now take `O(1)` - you just exclude the first non-excluded element.

**Option 4** If there are no duplicates, you can keep a `std::set` on the side with all excluded elements to this point. When you iterate, check whether the current element was already excluded or not.